# I can't see hokuyo_node information on rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need help.
I tried this tutorial ([link text](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/hokuyo_node%282f%29Tutorials%282f%29UsingTheHokuyoNode.html)), however I can see only black screen in rviz and the following error message is displayed:

> [ WARN] [1339998294.058023439]:
> Message from [/hokuyo_node] has a
> non-fully-qualified frame_id [laser].
> Resolved locally to [/laser].  This is
> will likely not work in multi-robot
> systems.  This message will only print
> once.

When I tried *rosnode hz scan*, the following message is displayed:

> subscribed to [/scan]
>  average
> rate: 10.057
>  min: 0.099s max:
> 0.100s std dev: 0.00046s window: 10
>  average rate: 10.059
>   min:
> 0.099s max: 0.100s std dev: 0.00044s window: 20
>  average rate:
> 10.056
>     min: 0.099s max: 0.100s std dev: 0.00047s window: 30
>  ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36679/i-can%27t-see-hokuyo_node-information-on-rviz./) by [s-kawakami](https://answers.ros.org/users/2637/s-kawakami/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Ensure that your fixed frame in rviz is set to /laser (as shown in the picture in the tutorial).
2. Scroll out (use mouse wheel) until you can see the whole grid. Sometimes you see only black because you are seeing only one portion of the grid

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1